# UPDATE table one... and INSERT into table two

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to `UPDATE` and `INSERT` into two different tables on the same user action, it has an error where it only completes the command of either the insert or the update depending on which line comes last.

Is there a way to combine these two ?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photos(user, gallery, filename, uploaddate)
        VALUES ('$log_username','profile pictures','$db_file_name',now())";

$sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar='$db_file_name'
        WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: you need to execute after each query

Comment: looks like you are over writing your first query with your second

Comment: Could you show more of your code? Like, where you're actually executing a SQL query? And what language is this? Perl?

Comment: can i write an IF condition?... if update = true then insert... ?? both commands are supposed to be for different tables but i want them to run together. i only want insert to run if the update has happened

Answer (score 0):

1) Execute the first query and then execute the second query.

2) use transaction if `mysql` if want want the successful execution of both the queries otherwise transaction control mechanism will revert the change.

And what error are you getting when you are firing the queries one by one

Comment: how do i execute both queries seperatly? but from the same button?

Comment: mysqli_query($connection, $sql). write this statement twice

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a trigger on the **photos** table? You could setup a tigger to execute every time an insert occurs that would update the **users** table.

Here's a link to check out: 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: this answer is beyond my understanding, im a very beginner

Comment: That's why I included a link.